# Thread method skipping 'if' statement

Tags: c#, multithreading, loops

When I try to use my method in created thread, thread skips 'if' statement in a loop. The problem is label4 is always shows else state. What should I do for the right operation? Here is my code;

This is where I create threads;

```
for(int i = 0; i <threads; i++)
{
    var tempThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DoWork));
    tempThread.Name = i.ToString();
    tempThread.Start();
}
CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
```

And this is what my thread method do;

```
public void DoWork()
{
    for(int i=2; i < variable/ 2; i++)
    {
        if (variable% i == 0) label4.Text ="yes not";
        else label4.Text = "yes";
    }
}
```

Comment: `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false` looks like you cheated instead of understanding the problem and fixing it the right way. This will bite you.

Comment: The variable is 'integer'. I'm onto understanding the threading logic, but this one is for my project and I don't have time for doing it the right way. But after the project, ofcourse I will understand the logic and next time I won't cheat :)

Comment: Updating a label inside a background thread won't work. Have you debugged this code? or is there some portion of it which you're not showing?

Comment: You will see, that it will throw an exception @ label4.Text. Use the bgworkers ProgressChanged-Event to give back stuff to the UI. Or Invoke your control.

Comment: Since there is no delay in your loop, this loop runs to the end and your label will always show the last text only. (And please avoid cross thread ui calls, try using `Control.Invoke` instead)

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov This is not the all code, but the problem is in these parts. When I debug the all code there is no problem but label don't show the right text.

Comment: "there is no problem but label don't show the right text" That sounds contradictory to me.

Comment: I assume you're working on Winforms. To fix your problem, read about `break` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adbctzc4.aspx) and `BeginInvoke` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke(v=vs.110).aspx). One will fix the logic of your code and the other will fix the cross thread exception you're ignoring.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I mean there is no debugging error..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing this is what you want to do, but since you haven't told us your goals we can only guess

```
public void DoWork()
{
    for(int i=2; i < variable/ 2; i++)
    {
        if (variable% i == 0) {
            label4.Text ="yes not";
            return;
        }
    }
    label4.Text = "yes";
}
```

I don't use C# but if DoWork is how you create a Thread then I think it's a bit much for something that should take almost no time at all to finish.

Comment: This is exactly what I need, thank you very much my friend.